# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a bricked Samsung Galaxy 3 tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, samsung, tablet

I'm not asking if it's *supported*, I'm asking if it's possible. I read up on the instructions for installing onto a tablet, but it tells me to allow USB debugging via my android tablet. Can I install without doing anything on my tablet? Because it won't turn on. Or am I just out of luck with this thing?

Comment: Ehm. The definition of "bricked" is that it is a "brick" meaning you can not do anything with it. "is it possible to install" has "no" as an answer if it is -bricked-.  Otherwise it is not bricked but just not functioning as it should be ;-)   "usb debugging" is set through the options of the tablet. And being able to "turning it on" is needed to install anything. So... I would say: no you can not. And getting it fixed is not done with Ubuntu. You need a firmware reset.

Answer (score 1):

### BASIC test for *possible*:

If you can't access **bootloader** or **recovery mode**, using the appropriate hold-key combo (eg. power plus volume-down, or whatever), then NO the device is fully bricked.

In which case you can NOT do anything further to recover/re-image the device from (Ubuntu) Linux.

---

### **UPDATE:**

You should be able to restore this device, using the recently (2015-Dec-09) released Android **v4.4.2** 'generic' firmware (http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/55365/T210RUEU0COI1_T210RXAC0COI1_XAC/) for this device.

**Note:** *This is perhaps too adventurous to do using **Heimdall** tool (under Ubuntu), so I recommend you instead use **Odin** tool (under Windows).*

- Create an account (if needed) on SamMobile.com;
- Search under **Firmware** section, for 'SM-T210R';
- Download version of **Odin** recommended (See **Instructions** provided)
- Download the firmware to your (Windows) PC, and unpack;
- Connect your tablet device (in 'Download Mode'), using USB cable;
- Follow instructions, to use Odin ..

---

*Happy for someone to provide details on how to do this, using **Heimdall** tool, on Ubuntu.*

Comment: OK so I pressed menu+vol-down+power and got into my devices [download mode](http://techbeasts.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/download-mode-samsung.jpg), is this a correct indication of it being possible? Is this what the guide talked about when it mentioned unlocking the bootloader?

Comment: Can you identify the exact model of tablet? eg. **SM-T311**, **GT-P3110** *You may be able to re-flash to ex-factory state using script (eg. from SamMobile: http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/).*

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy tab 3 Model: SM-T210R

Comment: We are not an android support site ;)

Comment: *And using Heimdall is too difficult to explain, as you have to build your own project files.*